# 'if' statement with modulus operator change method calls on button press

Tags: loops, if-statement, jtextfield

basically it's supposed to be a button that toggles whether a JTextfield is editable or not

i'm pretty much 100% sure there's a better way of doing this (this doesn't work)
i'm guessing a for loop?

```
while (e.getSource() == button2)
    {
        int count=0;//odd
        if (count % 2 == 0) // if count is even
        {
            textField1.setEditable(false);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            count++;
        }        
        else//odd
        {
            textField1.setEditable(true);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If e.Source()==button2 ¿doesn't it fall in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

Put the if/else statement inside the buttons `onClick()` method, so that it is called each time the button is clicked. Remove the while loop altogether.
Declare and initialise your count variable as a global variable (at the top of your activity, below the class name), as opposed to a local variable. 
Have the count variable incremented in the `onClick()` method, but before the if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should move 
    int count = 0;
before while.

This will prevent count to be reset on each iterarion and help to keep track of presses. Now, count is always equal 0 when condition is checked

Comment: program keeps freezing(stuck in a loop) when i run the button, not too sure why
(after i move the count outside the while loop)

Comment: Yeah, i missed that. After consuming a press, add break outside IF -else statement. This will stop loop execution but keeps press count

Comment: thank you!
it does stop the loop, however i can't seem to get it to toggle between calling the two methods